# Windows Server 2008 Web Edition Networked Printer Limitations

Tags: windows, web-server, network-printer

I am told by network admin that windows 2k8 web has a networked/shared printer cap, that is I can only see 10 networked printers but no more, I don't yet have an environment to prove it right or wrong, is that true? where is it documented?

We will setup 100 windows 7 pro or 8 pro work stations in a big WorkGroup. (yup, don't ask me why there is no domain) Each of them is attached to a USB printer, and each of these printers is shared on network. Meaning you can hook up to mine, I can print on yours.

Now, this 2k8 web server is among one of them in this WorkGroup. My question is, can this 2k8 server see and print on the 100 printers shared by each work station on the WorkGroup?

Answer (score 0):

I'm gonna go with "probably yes" since [Windows doesn't really have a practical hard limit on printers](https://serverfault.com/questions/367901/windows-server-becomes-unstable-when-too-many-printers-installed) (and I believe we accessed 100+ for a really messed up senior prank one year in high school from a netbook). If a netbook running basic windows 7 can do it, a server can do it.

The bottleneck is going to end up being drivers in all likelihood.